# Is there a way to have subfolder for every razor page when doing localization?

Tags: asp.net, localization

I have multiple razor pages which I would like to provide in multiple languages and I was wondering if I could create a folder structure for localization so that each page has its own subfolder.

For example, I have the following file:

> *Pages/GetData.razor*

When I put the resources files in following path everything works ok:

> *Resources/Pages/GetData.en.resx*
> *Resources/Pages/GetData.de.resx*

But what I really want is to have a subfolder for every page:

> *Resources/Pages/GetData/GetData.en.resx*
> *Resources/Pages/GetData/GetData.de.resx*

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What advantage would such a folder structure bring to you?

Comment: I feel like it would be a bit less cluttered since I will have to support about 6 languages and the amount of files in Resources/Pages would be considerable

Comment: Use a 3rd-party tool to do translations. ReSharper now has such a tool built right into VS. Also there is my free tool [Zeta Resource Editor](https://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/index.html) and there should be plenty other tools available that makes you work on a higher level than individual RESX files.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Thx for the tip :)